# Python copy to new list and exclude items

Tags: python

I have a 2d list in python3 that looks like this...

```
[
    [
        'item1',
        'item2',
        'item3',
        'item4'
    ],
    [
        'item1',
        'item2',
        'item3',
        'item4'
    ],
    [
        'item1',
        'item2',
        'item3',
        'item4'
    ]
]
```

I am trying to create a new list that only contains item1 and item 4 of each list so it would look like this..

```
[
    [
        'item1',
        'item4'
    ],
    [
        'item1',
        'item4'
    ],
    [
        'item1',
        'item4'
    ]
]
```

I am currently looping through the list and removing the elements with the remove() command.

This works but if I am in a situation where there are hundreds of different items then this is not efficient.

Is there a way I can copy to the new list but only keep [1] and [4] from each list?

Comment: `[[sublist[0], sublist[-1]] for sublist in superlist]`?

Comment: *"Is there a way I can copy..."* - only if you try it out. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b = [item for x in a for item in x if x.index(item) in [0,3]]
```

let a be your main list. this returns item in position 0,3. moreover you can add any other index to that list if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in 2 ways, a `for` loop or `list comprehension`

for loop:

```
new_list = []

for lst in main_list:
    new_list.append([lst[0], lst[-1]])
```

list comprehension:

```
new_list = [[lst[0], lst[-1]] for lst in main_list]
```

the `main_list` var is your original list.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to iterate over the list like so:

```
result = [[lst[0], lst[3]] for lst in list_2d]
```

This is called a list comprehension and is a convenient way to do for loops with lists.

`list_2d` is the original list.

`result` is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the functional programming way:

```
f = lambda x, j0, j1: list(map(lambda i: [x[i][j0], x[i][j1]], range(len(x))))

x = [
    [
        'item1',
        'item2',
        'item3',
        'item4'
    ],
    [
        'item1',
        'item2',
        'item3',
        'item4'
    ],
    [
        'item1',
        'item2',
        'item3',
        'item4'
    ]
]

print(f(x, 0, -1))

# [['item1', 'item4'], ['item1', 'item4'], ['item1', 'item4']]
```